# Execution time of creating a graph adt in C++

Tags: c++, performance, graph

Generally, is creating an undirected graph adt supposed to take a long time?

If I have a graph of 40 nodes, and each node is connected to 20% of the other nodes, my program will stall when it tries to link the nodes together.

The max I can really get up to is 20% density of 20 nodes. My code to link vertexes together looks like this:

```
    while(CalculateDensity()){
    LinkRandom();
    numLinks++;
}

void LinkRandom(){
int index = rand()%edgeList.size();
int index2 = rand()%edgeList.size();
edgeList.at(index).links.push_back(edgeList.at(index2));
edgeList.at(index2).links.push_back(edgeList.at(index));
}
```

Is there any way to do this faster?

EDIT: Here is where the data structure declaration:

```
    for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_NODES; i++){
    Node *ptr = new Node();
    edgeList.push_back(*ptr);       //populate edgelist with nodes
}
cout<<"edgelist populated"<<endl;
cout<<"linking nodes..."<<endl;
while(CalculateDensity()){
    LinkRandom();
    numLinks++;
}
```

Comment: What does `CalculateDensity()` return?

Comment: `numLinks<WEIGHT*((edgeList.size()*(edgeList.size()-1)));` where edgeList is a vector containing all nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you're copying a growing structure with each push_back.

That could be the cause of slowness.

If you could show the data structure declaration I could try to be more specific.

*edit* I still miss the Node declaration, nevertheless I would try to change the edgeList to a list of *pointers* to Node. Then

```
// hypothetic declaration
class Node {
  list<Node*> edgeList;
}

//populate edgelist with nodes
for(int i=0; i<TOTAL_NODES; i++)
  edgeList.push_back(new Node());
....

void LinkRandom(){
  int index = rand()%edgeList.size();
  int index2 = rand()%edgeList.size();
  edgeList.at(index)->links.push_back(edgeList.at(index2));
  edgeList.at(index2)->links.push_back(edgeList.at(index));
}
```

Comment: That was it. Coming from a Java background I thought that it would automatically create a pointer instead of sticking the whole object in the vector. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to properly delete Nodes instances when done!